# Remove pre and code tags from WordPress

Tags: the-content, content, escaping

WordPress has added both `<pre>` and `<code>` tags to my PHP embedded in a post.

Here's an example

```
<pre><code>register_taxonomy( 'Books', 'post',

array(
    'label' =&gt; __( 'Books' ),
) );
```

And here's what it should look like

```
register_taxonomy( 'Books', 'post',

array(
    'label' => __( 'Books' ),
) );
```

I know the arrow `>` symbol is changed by the code in my theme but the `<pre>` and `<code>` tags are added by a function within the WordPress core.

Does anybody know a filter or function which would enable me to remove these tags so the code displays correctly tags?

Comment: Are you using the Block Editor? If you paste your code into an actual Code block, it shouldn't add extra tags. If you're using Classic Editor, you might want to try looking at syntax highlighting plugins that will display things cleanly. I don't think WP Core adds tags such as `<pre>` on its own - have you tried using a different theme and deactivating plugins to make sure it's not something you have installed?

Comment: Yes however i'm using a now unsupported syntax highlighting plugin with the old text editor. If i change to the block editor it may cause lots of formatting errors.

Comment: You can use the Block Editor just on new posts. It will leave old posts alone until you go back and manually convert them. This might solve your immediate problem, and over time you can convert gradually until you can remove the old plugin that's causing issues.